# Loading Spring Properties in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, spring-boot

I am trying to create a class that contains values stored in property files in spring boot

so far I have the sample.properties file with the property "source.Ip" set.

The class is as follows:

```
@PropertySource({"classpath:sample.properties"})
@Configuration
@Component
public class PropertyLoader {

    @Value("${source.Ip}")
    private String sourceIp; 

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    public String getSourceIP(){
        return sourceIp;
    }

}
```

The property file is directly under src/main/resources which is a source folder.

However I get a :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'source.Ip' in string value "${source.Ip}"
```

As for my main class it is simply as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AppStarter {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(SpringApplication.run(AppStarter.class, args).getBean(PropertyLoader.class).getSourceIP());

    }

    @Bean
    public PropertyLoader propertyLoader(){
        return new PropertyLoader();
    }
}
```

sample.properties content:

```
source.Ip=127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to resolve `${...}` placeholders in `<bean>` definitions or `@Value` annotations using properties from a `PropertySource`, you must register a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. This happens automatically when using `<context:property-placeholder>` in `XML`, but must be explicitly registered using a static `@Bean` method when using `@Configuration` classes.

The method must be static for the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` Because `BeanFactoryPostProcessor (BFPP)` objects must be instantiated very early in the container lifecycle, they can interfere with processing of annotations such as `@Autowired`, `@Value`, and `@PostConstruct` within `@Configuration` classes.

Adding this to your application class should do the trick :

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    return pspc;
}
```

From the [PropertySource documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html).

**EDIT**

Have you try to

1. Put the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in the `AppStarter` class.
2. Move the `PropertySource` annotation to the `AppStarter` class.
3. Remove the `Configuration` annotation on the `PropertyLoader`.
4. Remove the propertyLoader method annotated with Bean.

The problem is probably related to the fact that the `PropertyLoader` is a component and a configuration class.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html

  This states that As of 3.1 PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is to be used. And it is present as a bean in my PropertyLoader

Comment: Have you try to put the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean in the AppStarter class?

Comment: Moving the PropertySource annotation was enough.

Comment: If you post the solution on it's own in the answer i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I edit my anwser. The problem was probably related to the fact that the PropertyLoader was a component and a configuration class.